# EasticSearch with multiple fuzzy parameters per column?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a table with columns as `Name` , `Address`and `Phone` and I want to run a elastic search query such as value of columns is

`Name` : `nametest`

`Address` : `addresstest`

`Phone` : `123456`

with fuzziness parameter as

`Name` : `2`

`Address` : `5`

`Phone` : `1`

A single query is

`{"query": {"match" : {"Address" : {"query" : "Address","fuzziness" : 2}}}}`

How to use multi-match query to obtain the result?

This isn't working

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": [
      {
        "Name": {
          "query": "Nametest",
          "fuzziness": 3,
          "boost": 5.0
        }
      },
      {
        "Address": {
          "query": "Addresstest",
          "fuzziness": 3,
          "boost": 4.0
        }
      },
      {
        "Phone": {
          "query": "5680728.00",
          "fuzziness": 2,
          "boost": 4.0
        }
      }

    ],
    "must": [
    ],
    "minimum_should_match": 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to combine multiple `must` clauses. Those clauses will be mandatory match for your document and will be use to calculate the score. If you want at least 2 clauses to match, you can use the `minimum_should_match` parameter and transfer all condition to `should` clauses.

In those clauses you can use a match query as you tried.

example :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "Name": {
              "query": "Nametest",
              "fuzziness": 3,
              "boost": 5
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Address": {
              "query": "Addresstest",
              "fuzziness": 3,
              "boost": 4
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Phone": {
              "query": "5680728.00",
              "fuzziness": 2,
              "boost": 4
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_number_should_match": 2
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean query

```
GET query
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "Name": {
              "query": "Nametest",
              "fuzziness": 3,
              "boost": 5
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Address": {
              "query": "Addresstest",
              "fuzziness": 3,
              "boost": 4
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Phone": {
              "query": "5680728.00",
              "fuzziness": 2,
              "boost": 4
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this query will not respect the original minimum_should_match of the question. But i not sure the original mininum_should_match is intentional :|